# django-cms urls with Slug at Root

Tags: django, django-urls, django-cms

In my url.py I have:

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^tinymce/', include('tinymce.urls')),
    url(r'^', include('cms.urls')),
    url(r'^journal/', include('zinnia.urls')),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django.contrib.comments.urls')),
)
```

and

```
urlpatterns += patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', PremiumListingDetailView.as_view(), name='premium_listing'),
)
```

I would like to have urls for premium listing's slug at http://www.example.com/slug to show the DetailView. The page loads if I place the Premium Listing's urls before django-cms but the rest of the cms pages will not be shown, e.g. going to http://www.example.com/about will throw a 404. If I place it after the cms' include urls, going to http://www.example.com/slug will not work.

How should I structure the urls file to achieve what I need? For now, I am attaching a tilde  in front of the listing urls as such: `url(r'^~(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$, ...)` which may not be the best solution.

Comment: Please add the cms.urls code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url intended for app x is matched against a pattern of app y. The view can't match the slug and returns a 404 not found.

The pattern `r'^'` or `r'^(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$'` should come last because it will catch anything. Use only one of the two because they match the same (see the cms.urls). Consider a PremiumListingDetailView object with the slug **comments**. At this moment it would highjack the comments app. Putting the wide matching pattern last, the important patterns will always take precedence.

The simple (and future proof) way of fixing pattern collision is making patterns unique:

```
url(r'^cms/', include('cms.urls')), # Added cms/
```

Now if the slug is not *tinymce*, *cms*, *journal* or *comments* it ends up in PremiumListingDetailView.

Alternatively you can make PremiumListingDetailView pattern unique (you did this with tilde):

```
url(r'^list/(?P<slug>[-\w\d]+)/$', # Added list/
    PremiumListingDetailView.as_view(), 
    name='premium_listing'),

url(r'^', include('cms.urls')), # CMS comes after.
```

But what if cms has a view at `list/something/`? The cms view won't be reached. The request will be handled by PremiumListingDetailView and the slug **something** won't exist resulting in a 404.

Technically you can put the PremiumListingDetailView pattern in cms.urls where you'll have fine grained control over when a cms or PremiumListingDetailView pattern is matched but the patterns are still likely to collide. This will violate the loose coupling principle. It will bite you.

Conclusion: Include apps at unique urls. Make sure each pattern in an app is unique. Wide matching patterns should come after more important patterns.

Comment: Hi allcaps, thanks for your concise and clear answer. Your conclusion was exactly what I thought, especially the hijacking part when patterns are exactly the same. Thanks for pointing out how to future proof the urls and where collisions may unexpectedly crop up.